# React-Redux migration from 5.x to 7.x broke `connect`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to upgrade from react-redux (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux) to 7.x from 5.x, to use hooks and have reached some breaking changes with the connect() function. It keeps giving me an error that I must wrap my app in a provider, which I already have.

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(DateRangeSelector)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(DateRangeSelector)".
```

Provider Code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from 'scripts/setup';
import FullReactComponent from 'root/FullReactComponent';


const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <FullReactComponent />
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

Connect code:

```js
FullReactRootComponent.propTypes = {
  bgColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export const mapStateToProps = ({ portal }) => ({
  bgColor: portal.get('bgColor'),
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchEnabledRoutes: actions.fetchEnabledRoutes,
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(FullReactRootComponent);
```

Has anyone ran into this issue upgrading as well? Is there a change in the connect API?

Edit: Here's an example of how Connect isn't being called properly between two snapshots:

5.x:

```js
 <Connect(ModalComponent) open={true}>
   <ModalAdd /> 
</Connect(ModalComponent)>
```

7.x:

```js
<ModalComponent
  open={true}
/>
```

Comment: Breaking changes in v6 are listed here: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0. Likewise, for v7: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1

Comment: but the code looks pretty good to me, the broken part should be somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah i read the release notes, and it seems to be non breaking from 5.x since major thrash was in 6.x with removing the ability to move the store.

Comment: Do you accidentally have multiple versions of React-Redux in the app somehow?

Comment: That does seem to be the issue, there's another package that uses 5.x and wanted to upgrade to 7.x, so there's a conflict

Comment: You know your getting good advice when @markerikson comes to debug your redux issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @markerikson, it turned out I had duplicate copies of react-redux in my yarn.lock. To fix, I put react-redux in `resolutions` in package.json, and forced it to be 7.x for any shared libraries.